# Incorporating data in to R packages from a external file

Tags: r

I've been using http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz as a guide with much success,  but I'm stuck on something that I haven't been able to resolve for many hours. Perhaps because I'm a bit thick...

Basically, I want to include a bunch of `csv`'s as data.frames into an R package I'm working on. If I manually save the data objects as `.rda` or `.Rdata` and place them in the `<package_dir>/data` folder, I can build the package and the data is accessible upon loading the package. However, these `csv`'s will receive updates every so often, and when this happens I'd like to just hit 'build' in R-Studio and have the data objects rebuilt from the `csv`'s using some very simple processing scripts I have written.

So based on Hadley's guide, I've run `devtools::use_data_raw()` and put the `csv`'s in the `<package_dir>/data-raw` folder. In that folder I've also placed R scripts to turn these data files in to R objects and then save them to the correct location and with the correct format with `devtools::use_data(<object_name>)`.

My original interpretation was that that when building the package, the scripts in `<package_dir>/data-raw` get run to produce the `.rda` files in the `<package_dir>/data` folder. I'm guessing this is incorrect? If this is wrong, is there a way to automatically source those scripts when building the package? Is/would this be a bad practice?